# Regex expression giving false value even when correcting the input

Tags: c#, forms

I wrote a regex expression to make sure that the user is entering the correct format in the textboxes, if the user entered a wrong value a warning will appear, The problem is: when correcting the input to the right format it will still show the warning statement and won't go to the other form. And I don't understand why.

```
 if (txtFirstName.Text.Length == 0 || txtLastName.Text.Length == 0 || txtEmail.Text.Length == 0 || txtEmail.Text.Length == 0 || txtPassword.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Make sure to fill All text boxes!");
            }
            else
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(txtFirstName.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z]$"))
                {
                    MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
                    mainMenu.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    lblWarning.Visible = true;
                    txtFirstName.Text = " ";
                }

                if (Regex.IsMatch(txtLastName.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z]$"))
                {
                    MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
                    mainMenu.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    lblWarning2.Visible = true;
                    txtLastName.Text = " ";
                }

                if (Regex.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text, @"^[a-zA-z]{1-10}@(gmail|hotmail|cloud).(com|org)$"))
                {
                    MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
                    mainMenu.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    lblWarning3.Visible = true;
                    txtEmail.Text = " ";
                }

                if (Regex.IsMatch(txtPhoneNumber.Text, @"^[0-9]{10}$"))
                {
                    MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
                    mainMenu.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    lblWarning4.Visible = true;
                    txtPhoneNumber.Text = " ";
                }
```

Comment: can you reproduce the issue with **only 1** field validation (your question has 4 repeated ones)?

Comment: I don't know how to do this actually

Comment: remove unnecessary code, provide a **minimal** reproducible code.

Comment: Yes I understand, but i don't know how to write 4 regex expressions for 4 different textboxes into 1 validation field.

Comment: then if you have 100 fields in production, you'll paste all code here?

Comment: What is the input you typed to test these regexp? Please provide.

Comment: first and last name : 2 / email: hello / phone number: hello 
,  then i corrected each input by entering the correct format

Comment: first and last name accepts `[a-zA-Z]` so `2` won't work. It only accepts alphabets.
email needs a `@` and domain following that symbol., `hello` won't work.
phone number takes `[0-9]{10}` which means 10 numbers, `hello` won't work.

Comment: Yes I know, my problem is when I enter an incorrect format (for example 2 for the first name) and then click on the button a warning statement will appear like: `Enter only letters`, so when I enter a name using letters only. the same statement will appear when clicking the button like it was an error.

Comment: Then you need to check the code where it shows `Enter only letters`, and fix that part according to your need. If it's your colleague's code, ask them. The code you provided above didn't have the part where it says `Enter only letters`

Comment: `Enter only letters` is in a label and this `lblWarning.Visible = true;` will make it visible for the user. I tried to fix this error multiple times but didn't figure it out. Thank you for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.IsMatch(txtFirstName.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$")
```

your regex will only match txtFirstName consisting of one letter.

Comment: I added the + sign but it didn't work, I still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex from

`@"^[a-zA-z]{1-10}@(gmail|hotmail|cloud).(com|org)$"`

to

`@"^[a-zA-z]{1,10}@(gmail|hotmail|cloud)\.(com|org)$"`

Comment: I changed but i still have the same error